# Problemas para iniciar windows en dual boot con arclinux

Tags: windows, archlinux

acabo de de instalar archlinux en mi pc que ya tenía instalado windows, pero al parecer la instalación de grub no reconoció el inicio de windows, ya que cuado prendo el pc en el ménu de inicio no me muestra la opción de windows, no se que hacer para solucionar este problema

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este sitio es sobre programacion. tu pregunta iria mejor en un sitio sobre linux o sistemas operativos....

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener los siguientes requisitos:

- El Disco en GPT
- La Partición UEFI en el sistema Linux

Tendrás que volver a instalar ambos sistemas para que funcionen creo, soy nuevo y tuve el mismo problema con Regolith (Ubuntu) así que creo que con eso será suficiente.

Igual investiga un poco mas ya que yo también soy novel en este tema